# I am trying to insert new customer using google reseller api of node.I am getting 400 error

Tags: node.js, google-reseller-api

//parmeter

```
var params = {
"auth":auth,
"kind": "reseller#customer",
"customerId": "customerId",
"customerDomain": "customer domain",
"postalAddress": {
  "kind": "customers#address",
  "contactName": "John Doe",
  "organizationName": "Example Inc",
  "postalCode": "94043",
  "countryCode": "US",

},
"alternateEmail": "email address  "
```

}
//using api

```
var service = google.reseller('v1');
service.customers.insert(params,function(err,data){
   console.log(err);
   console.log(data); 
})
```

Iam getting this error:

```
{ [Error: Invalid Value]
  code: 400,
  errors: [ { domain: 'global', reason: 'invalid', message: 'Invalid Value' } ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module to perform this action in easy way.

here is an example to insert a `customer` execute it

> POST `https://www.googleapis.com/apps/reseller/v1/customers`

```
    Body parameter

  {
  "kind": "reseller#customer",
  "customerId": "custId-1234",
  "customerDomain": "example.com",
  "postalAddress": {
    "kind": "customers#address",
    "contactName": "John Doe",
    "organizationName": "Example Inc",
    "postalCode": "94043",
    "countryCode": "US",
  },
  "alternateEmail": "alternateEmail@google.com"
}
```

For more [reference](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/how-tos/manage_customers)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is stated in your error logs already.

> reason: message: 'Invalid Value'

`"auth":auth` is not included in the [Customers resource](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/reference/customers/insert).

These are the valid values:

```
{
  "kind": "reseller#customer",
  "customerId": string,
  "customerDomain": string,
  "postalAddress": {
    "kind": "customers#address",
    "contactName": string,
    "organizationName": string,
    "locality": string,
    "region": string,
    "postalCode": string,
    "countryCode": string,
    "addressLine1": string,
    "addressLine2": string,
    "addressLine3": string
  },
  "phoneNumber": string,
  "alternateEmail": string,
  "resourceUiUrl": string,
  "customerDomainVerified": boolean
}
```